# MySQL error: Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1241

I have this MySQL Query **(working)**

First query:

```
SELECT id
FROM users
WHERE publisher_set = '1'
AND publisher_status = '1'
AND publisher_content != ''
AND publisher_amount != '0'
AND publisher_now < publisher_max
AND EXISTS (

SELECT *
FROM user_counter
WHERE users.id = user_counter.publisher_id
)
```

The MySQL query above is to find the user id from two table

Now I want to compared again using this second MySQL query **(working)**

Second query:

```
SELECT users.id, publisher_amount, publisher_now, publisher_max, counter
FROM users
INNER JOIN user_counter ON users.id = user_counter.publisher_id
WHERE no = 08123456789
AND counter < publisher_amount
```

But when I join all the query like this:

```
SELECT id
FROM users
WHERE publisher_set = '1'
AND publisher_status = '1'
AND publisher_content != ''
AND publisher_amount != '0'
AND publisher_now < publisher_max
AND EXISTS (

SELECT *
FROM user_counter
WHERE users.id = user_counter.publisher_id
)

AND (
SELECT users.id, publisher_amount, publisher_now, publisher_max, counter
FROM users
INNER JOIN user_counter ON users.id = user_counter.publisher_id
WHERE no =08123456789
AND counter < publisher_amount
)
```

I get this error:

> Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Then, I try using 1 column, but the result is not what I wanted.

My question is How to join first and second query ? and produce no error.

I have tried google it and after many "try-and-error" this is the far I can get to make the query work.

Comment: Sub query is returning more than 1 column ;) after `EXISTS (`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just miss an EXISTS on your second subquery. Anyway, if I understand your query correctly, I think you could write your query as this:

```
SELECT
  u.id
FROM
  users u inner join user_counter uc
  on u.id=uc.publisher_id
     and no=08123456789
     and counter < publisher_amount
WHERE
  u.publisher_set = '1'
  AND u.publisher_status = '1'
  AND u.publisher_content != ''
  AND u.publisher_amount != '0'
  AND u.publisher_now < publisher_max
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change the first EXISTS clause to:

```
and users.id in (select user_counter.publisher_id from user_counter)
```

and use EXISTS on the final query.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this:

```
AND EXISTS (

SELECT user_counter.publisher_id
FROM user_counter
WHERE users.id = user_counter.publisher_id
```

---

PS: SQLFIDDLE doesn't work in my end for some reason. Else would have been happy to give you a demonstration ;)

Comment: Had some strange issues with SQL Fiddle this morning.  Should be working now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id
FROM users
WHERE publisher_set = '1'
AND publisher_status = '1' 
AND publisher_content != ''
AND publisher_amount != '0'
AND publisher_now < publisher_max
AND EXISTS (
select 1 from  user_counter where  users.id = user_counter.publisher_id
    and  no =08123456789
AND counter < publisher_amount
)
```

Assuming `no` and `counter` are on table `user_counter`. A bit hard to tell without a schema.